# ASP.NET Core doesn't create XML comments file

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am using Swashbuckle for Api documentation, which requires projectname.xml document from the output, but when i build my ASP.NET Core project I don't get that file.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger

Visual Studio has an option to generate the XML file but how can I do that from console?

Here is my ASP.NET Core version:

```
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview2-1-003177)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2017 and the `dotnet` CLI, setting the `DocumentationFile` property in the .csproj file will generate XML documentation at the specified path, relative to the project file. For example, to generate the XML doc in the same directory as your built assembly, you can add the following property group to the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <DocumentationFile>bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\MyProject.xml</DocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you only want it built for particular configurations or platforms, make sure to set an appropriate `Condition` on the property group.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still using Visual Studio 2015, you can do it in the project.json by adding `xmlDoc` to `buildOptions`

```
"buildOptions": {
    "xmlDoc": true,
}
```

Visual Studio 2017 (*.csproj structure) I am not sure. But when you set it via Visual Studio it will be persisted in the csproj/project.json file.